# Should I respond to students who plead for increasing grade

Tags: teaching

I use GradeScope for grading exams and quizzes in my courses and ask students to submit regrade requests only for objective mistakes, such as misreading numbers. Despite this, I receive many requests that don't meet this criterion, and sometimes, students send long emails pleading their cases even after I've rejected their regrade requests. These situations can be frustrating, and while part of me wants to ignore these emails—many of which seem to be generated by AI like ChatGPT—I also strive to be empathetic.

Does anyone have guidelines or practices they follow when dealing with students who plead for better grades?

I'm considering creating an FAQ on my website to address this and direct students to it when faced with such situations. Would this be too cold?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/204792/appropriate-smart-ways-to-decline-students-requests-of-begging-for-better-grad Closely related, maybe duplicate.

Comment: "I […] ask students to submit regrade requests only for objective mistakes" How do you do so? Is this verbally at the start of the course, in some course description, the lecture material, ...?

Comment: It is in the syllabus and has been repeated in an email, announcement.

Comment: Are you asking about exams only, or more generally, such as required homework? And, is it for work during a term or only for final evaluations?

Comment: Exams. I don't give homework, only several quizzes and a final exam.

Comment: What scale are you asking about? 30 students? 300?

Comment: You object to ChatGPT, but isn't GradeScope, itself, driven by an AI?

Comment: @Buffy I don’t object to chatGPT. 
 But I do hope they ask chatGPT to make their emails a bit more concise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to already have everything<sup>1</sup> needed, you just have to consistently use it. Always make sure to clearly communicate the rules you have set:

> I'm sorry, but as announced in [the lecture/the syllabus/via email/...] regrade requests are only accepted for objective mistakes.

Your message is a simple one, an additional FAQ would only needlessly duplicate it or open room for interpretation.
Sticking to this message is important to be fair towards *all* your students, especially those that accept your rules from the get go. But also for those trying to bend the rules it is important to not get stringed along.

Now, if you have the interpersonal skills to *also* reach out to students, then if you feel they need your help by all means do so. There are a lot of situations in which grading is not the root problem, so you should be able to help out without muddying the line on your established rules. But do this only if you feel up for the task.

---

<sup>1</sup> If your institution has an office for handling special circumstances (e.g. disabilities, illness, ...) you might want to note this as well.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I normally just give them the points. I've used GradeScope before and I hated seeing the responses. I would spend so much energy being angry and needing to justify my original assessment. The truth is, I don't care that much. Clearly the student cares, or they wouldn't be asking.

I dislike grading and work to move away from it. The students worrying about points distracts from learning the concepts. Now, I have them write a self-assessment and submit it. There's no argument, and I get a better understanding of each student's learning experience.

I recommend reading [Alfie Kohn](https://www.alfiekohn.org/article/case-grades/?ref=jesse-stommel&print=print) and [Jessie Stommel](https://www.jessestommel.com/why-i-dont-grade/). Those are who changed my approach to grades.

Comment: What is your field?

Comment: thanks for sharing the links. I was not aware of self-assessments before.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote after reading the first sentence, but after reading the whole thing, I will upvote instead. Not that I necessarily agree with you, but this is an interesting viewpoint.

Comment: I would get in trouble if I don’t give grades.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  Do you see any gender/racial/socioeconomic patterns in which students advocate the hardest for higher grades?  Because *other* people give grades more importance than you do, are you inadvertently propagating existing discrimination? I'd hate to think that students with imposter syndrome get lower grades in your classes because they don't know to simply ask for a higher grade.

Comment: Not giving grade has a significant problem is that students need grade to apply for graduate schools. No graduate school admission officers will spend that time going through non-quantitative reports on a student's performance. Ranking students by grades is much easier.

Answer (score 3):

What your process seems to be missing is a procedure that deals with exceptional circumstances. So your students are using the procedure that is closest to it. That is bad, mainly because it encourages students with special circumstances to wait until after the grades are in, while special circumstances need to be discussed as quickly as possible. That way there are many more options open to let that student participate and learn to the maximum that those special circumstances allow, rather than just "adjust the grade" after the course is done.

So I would suggest that you add to the syllabus that students need to come to your office hours if they t think they need special accommodation on top of what the university normally allows for disabilities etc. They need to do so as soon as that special circumstance occurs. You will allow for some reasonable delay (you don't have to discharge yourself from hospital), but waiting till after the grades are in or a deadline has passed is too late. The purpose of the accommodation is to allow you to participate. Once the course is over, you obviously can no longer participate and the accommodation would serve no purpose.